# Can't download files with cron

Tags: bash, cron

I have one script that allows me to download a number of files from an FTP server. When I execute manually it works as expected, but when I schedule the script with cron it executes but doesn't download the files.

My script is....

```
#!/bin/bash
FECHA=$(date +%Y%m%d)
FECHAHH=${FECHA}00
DIRECTORY="/home/usuario/DATA/"
FECHAHH1="gfs."$FECHAHH
gfs="gfs."
URL="url_of_ftp"
FILE=$DIRECTORY"file"
FILEDWL=$URL"/file"
echo $DIRECTORY
echo $URL
echo $FILE
valor1=0
valor2=1
for ((i=0;i<=120;i+=6)); do
    J=0$i
    if [ $i -le 10 ] ; then
       FILET=$FILE$J
       FILEDWLT=$FILEDWL$J
    else
       FILET=$FILE$i
       FILEDWLT=$FILEDWL$i
    fi
    if [ -f $FILET ]; then
       valor1=`expr $valor1 "+" $valor2`
       echo el fichero $FILEDWLT existe
    else
       echo "Bajando ARCHIVO " $FILEDWLT
       curl -O $FILEDWLT
    fi
 echo $valor1

 if [ $valor1 -eq 21 ] ; then
    echo "Comenzar proceso " >> $FECHAHH.txt
 fi
 done
 echo "fIN"
```

The script has the proper permissions. What I'm doing wrong?

Thanks..

Comment: is the crontab "owner" the same userID as the one you use on the cmd-line?

Comment: Hi shellter, yes. Is the root.

Comment: what happens when you run it as in:  bash -x $script --- the xtrace output will say a lot.

Comment: all seems normal, it's like it download the file... but I can't saw it.

Comment: Where are you saving the downloaded files? In the current working directory? Or in some absolute path? Should it be like `curl $FILEDWLT -O $FILET`?

Comment: That was the problem, the destination folder, it was wrong. Thansk for the help.